# Guardar los campos de DataGridView en un XML

Tags: c#, xml, gridview

Tengo un pequeño problema que no puedo solucionar, tengo un `GridView` con 3 columnas específicas, lo que necesito es guardar esas 3 columnas en un XML y no logro hacerlo.

El xml que quiero formar es es mas o menos así.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
<Fila1>
    <Columna1>Ejemplo</Columna1>
    <Columna2>Ejemplo</Columna2>
    <Columna3>Ejemplo</Columna3>
</Fila1>
<Fila2>
    <Columna1>Ejemplo</Columna1>
    <Columna2>Ejemplo</Columna2>
    <Columna3>Ejemplo</Columna3>
</Fila2>
<Fila3>
    <Columna1>Ejemplo</Columna1>
    <Columna2>Ejemplo</Columna2>
    <Columna3>Ejemplo</Columna3>
</Fila3>
</NewDataSet>
```

y el DataGridView que tengo es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que debes hacer es guardar los datos del grid en un dataset. Para eso puedes hacer un método de extensión para que esté disponible en cualquier grid:

```
public static class DataGridViewExtensions
{
    public static DataSet GetDataSet(this DataGridView dgv) 
    {
        var ds = new DataSet();
        var dt = new DataTable();

        foreach (var column in dgv.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()) 
        {
            if (column.Visible) 
            {
                dt.Columns.Add();
            }
        }

        var cellValues = new object[dgv.Columns.Count];
        foreach (var row in dgv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()) 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++) 
            {
                cellValues[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(cellValues);
        }
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        return ds;
    }
}
```

Ya con eso, cuando quieras guardar la información del grid en un xml haces eso:

```
var dataSet = dgvGrid.GetDataSet();
dataSet.WriteXml(File.OpenWrite("archivo.xml"));
```

dgvGrid es el grid que quieres exportar a xml, y "archivo.xml" es la ruta donde vas a guardar el xml.

No lo he probado en visual studio, avisa si te sale algún error.

Comment: solo una consulta a la hora de gurdar el XML de donde sacas la linea. **var dataSet = dgvGrid.GetDataSet();** me marca como error **.GetDataSet();**

Comment: En donde y con qué namespace guardaste la primera parte del código?

Comment: y para eliminar el archivo.XML guardado, con el button limpiar o borrar en el datagriview, como le hago?

Comment: @angelfarias quieres eliminar el archivo xml o limpiar el grid?